# How to scan barcode lines with VARCHAR Chars For example OfficeEqp35023U11 In android Kotlin without spaces

Tags: java, android, kotlin, barcode

How to scan barcode lines with VARCHAR Chars For example OfficeEqp35023U11 In android Kotlin

Struggling to scan this asset image
[Struggling to scan this asset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVzoC.jpg)

class BarcodeScannerActivity :  AppCompatActivity(), ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
private var mScannerView: ZXingScannerView? = null
lateinit var apiInterface: APIInterface

```
public override fun onCreate(state: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(state)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode_scanner)



    ssoId = intent.getStringExtra("initiator")
    val contentFrame = findViewById<View>(R.id.content_frame) as ViewGroup

    mScannerView = ZXingScannerView(this)
    contentFrame.addView(mScannerView)
}
```

public override fun onResume() {
super.onResume()
mScannerView!!.setResultHandler(this)
mScannerView!!.startCamera()
}

```
public override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mScannerView!!.stopCamera()
}


override fun handleResult(rawResult: Result) {
    Toast.makeText(
        this, "Contents = " + rawResult.text +
                ", Format = " + rawResult.barcodeFormat.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
    ).show()
    var result = rawResult.text

    if (result.isDigitsOnly()) {

        assetTag = result.filter { it.isLetterOrDigit()  }


        mScannerView!!.stopCamera()
        apiInterface = APIClient.client!!.create(APIInterface::class.java)

        val call: Call<Verifiedd> =
            apiInterface.saveVerification(assetTag, ssoId, ssoId, "Verified", "Verified")

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<Verifiedd> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Verifiedd>, response: Response<Verifiedd>) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    lovelyProgressDialog?.dismiss()
                    Log.d("TAG", response.code().toString() + "")
                    var displayResponse = ""
                    val resource: Verifiedd = response.body()!!
                    responseCode = resource.responseCode
                    responseMessage = resource.responseMessage
                    if (responseMessage == "Data persisted successfully " || responseMessage.equals(
                            "Data persisted successfully "
                        )
                    ) {
                        Toasty.normal(
                            this@BarcodeScannerActivity,
                            "",
                            Toasty.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()


                    } else if (responseMessage == "" || responseMessage.equals(
                            ""
                        )
                    ) {
                        Toasty.normal(
                            this@BarcodeScannerActivity,
                            "Invalid Asset Verification status values",
                            Toasty.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                        val intent =
                            Intent(this@BarcodeScannerActivity, BranchItemsActivity::class.java)
                        intent.flags =
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                        intent.putExtra(
                            "initiator", ssoId
                        )



                        startActivity(intent)

                    }

                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Verifiedd>, t: Throwable) {
                Toasty.normal(
                    this@BarcodeScannerActivity,
                    "Server Error",
                    Toasty.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
        })
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to scan barcode that includes VARCHAR characters OfficeEqp35023U11 in kotlin. once the barcode is scanned I then called rest API to pass the result. I tried every tutorial to scan alphanumeric barcode lines using ZXingScannerView library. I am passing assettag as parameter in Rest API. Previously I have to scan barcode that have spaces in barcode lines for example Office EqP35023U11 (It was working fine) Now I have to scan barcode without spaces such as OfficeEqp35023U11

Comment: Post your code as code not as picture

Comment: Kindly check now.